# Merge commit messages result in duplicate comments

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, jira, git-merge

I'm using Smart Commit to integrate Jira and Gitlab.

Commits messages are added on the Jira card.

The problem I'm having is that when a branch is mergeed, all messages are being duplicated on the card.

Has anyone had this problem?

I'm using Jira Cloud and GitLab Community Edition 8.10.4 942d997